# Why does not work Puppeteer-firefox on servers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to run on Windows Server 2008 and 2016
Are there any solutions to launch it? I searched a lot but found nothing.
I get an error:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\_t>node app.js
ERROR: The process "1212" not found.
(node:4276) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Failed to launch Firefox!


    at onClose (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\_t\node_modules\puppeteer-firefox
\lib\Launcher.js:263:14)
    at Interface.helper.addEventListener (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\_t\node
_modules\puppeteer-firefox\lib\Launcher.js:252:50)
    at Interface.emit (events.js:187:15)
    at Interface.close (readline.js:379:8)
    at Socket.onend (readline.js:157:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:187:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1094:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
  -- ASYNC --
    at Puppeteer.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\_t\node_modules\pup
peteer-firefox\lib\helper.js:31:27)
    at C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\_t\a.js:253:21
    at afterLogin (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\_t\a.js:277:4)
    at Object.start (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\_t\a.js:101:2)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\_t\app.js:156:7)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:282:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
(node:4276) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch
block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection
 id: 1)
(node:4276) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are depre
cated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
 Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

On Ubuntu server:

```
(node:7869) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Failed to launch Firefox!


    at onClose (/root/node_modules/puppeteer-firefox/lib/Launcher.js:263:14)
    at Interface.helper.addEventListener (/root/node_modules/puppeteer-firefox/lib/Launcher.js:252:50)
    at Interface.emit (events.js:194:15)
    at Interface.close (readline.js:379:8)
    at Socket.onend (readline.js:157:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:194:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1103:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
  -- ASYNC --
    at Puppeteer.<anonymous> (/root/node_modules/puppeteer-firefox/lib/helper.js:31:27)
    at /root/a.js:255:21
    at afterLogin (/root/a.js:269:4)
    at Object.start (/root/a.js:102:2)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/app.js:156:7)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
(node:7869) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:7869) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Does it work on at least some server?
Everything works fine on my Desktop computer.

**Requires a version for working with the Firefox**
[Puppeteer-firefox](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/tree/master/experimental/puppeteer-firefox)

Comment: make sure `headless` is not `false`?

Comment: Please note that to launch a firefox you have to have a desktop environment installed on the machine. Most server OSes don't have desktop environments by default.

Comment: I tried to specify the headless as true and false
I checked the presence of all the necessary environment variables
I ran puppeteer which works with chrome on the same servers. But to work with firefox (puppeteer-firefox) can not start.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (failed to Launch Firefox) on my VPS Windows.

So i went to **node_modules/puppeteer-firefox/.local-browser/.../firefox.exe** and i tried to open it. I had the **0xc00007b error** when i tried to open the exe file.

Download "All in One Runtimes" for Windows and start the installation of all softwares. I maked this and this works for me.
Try it and tell me !

*Edit: (sorry for the bad english)*

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use the `puppeteer-firefox` package anymore. It has been deprecated.
Experimental support for Firefox is included in the official `puppeteer` package now.

Here an [example from the Puppeteer repository](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/examples/cross-browser.js) in how to run your script against Firefox:

```
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch(firefoxOptions);

  const page = await browser.newPage();
  console.log(await browser.version());

  await page.goto('https://news.ycombinator.com/');

  // Extract articles from the page.
  const resultsSelector = '.storylink';
  const links = await page.evaluate((resultsSelector) => {
    const anchors = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(resultsSelector));
    return anchors.map((anchor) => {
      const title = anchor.textContent.trim();
      return `${title} - ${anchor.href}`;
    });
  }, resultsSelector);
  console.log(links.join('\n'));

  await browser.close();
})();
```

If there is still a problem in launching Firefox, then please let us know and we can get it fixed.